# boost::split will change the input string when the input string is not const?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

The parameters of boost::split function are not constant. Will `boost::split` change the input string or move it into another memory address when it's not constant?

The background of question: my service is written in C++, it's always core dump. I am trying to find the reason. My code uses the `boost::split` function, and passes a non-constant reference of a string to `boost::split`. The code will run multithreaded, so I think it's not thread safe and result in a core dump.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::split()` does not modify its arguments ([see the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.split_hpp)). More likely reason is that you are modifying the string in one thread, while `boost::split` is reading it in another. To avoid this, protect your variables using a [mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read the boost documents( including your pasted link), the documents not mention wether modify its arguments. If the boost::split will not change the arguments, why the parameter of input string not set to constant?